# Country/Municipality/Locality implementation

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

```
 http://baseuri.com/year/month/day/continent/country/municipality/locality/article
```

I am seeking to implement a URI like the one above using MVC for a news application. Are there any sites anyone can point me to with similar urls?

IS there a pit fall in constructing a URL like this. I am considering a vanity URL approach on articles. Is this logical. Thanks.

Comment: This seems horribly bloated, and any vanity will be gone seeing as the URLs will be super long. Does all this stuff really need to be in the URL? What kind of a site is this for?

Comment: continent is probably too much, state is logically before city (and not available for most countries of the world), municipality overlaps with city, and locality is often not available

Comment: No, there are no similar sites using that URL pattern because it's a horrible pattern. Please rethink this.

Comment: Thanks there were some mistakes in my first post. Sites Like CNN and BBC use "/year/month/day/continent/country/" for world news. I am seeking a way to implement the rest of the pattern for post down to a district.

Comment: The Closest I have seen thus far is"http://www.bikemap.net/en/regional/United+States/New+York/Clifton+Park/#/z11/42.82058,-73.7938/terrain"